# Gradle, iterating over the downloaded dependency Jar's and extract a specific file using Gradle Task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Once Gradle has downloaded the dependencies I'm trying to iterate over each jar file, extract a specific file, swagger yml, into a folder. However, when I execute the task it returns NO-SOURCE.

The task to extract the file into a folder:

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    configurations.artifact.asFileTree.each {
        from zipTree(it).matching { include "OpenApi-*.yml" }
        into 'swaggerExtract/'
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
configurations {
    artifact
}

dependencies {
    artifact 'com.example.android:accounts-service:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'
    artifact 'com.example.android:my-service:0.0.4.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
```